# webserver(IIS) to be allowed to access folders on other network servers

Tags: iis, permissions

I'm trying to use filexists in php to check if a file exists on a network server.

It keeps coming back with false and I think this is probably to do with permissions, as it seems to work from localhost and not the webserver I'm running it from.

I've tried to log the World Wide Web Publishing on as a network admin, but when restart the service I get the error message

Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process.

Basically I think I need permissions for the webserver(IIS) to be allowed to access folders on other network servers.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer just permissions setting as thought:

Go into the Properties for the IIS web-site, Directory Security tab. Edit anonymous access and authentication Edit the account used for anonymous access Select a network login account with the required privileges

sorted